# Список в boostrap 3

Tags: html, bootstrap

Как реализовать вот такой список в bootstrap 3?

[image: список]

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вопрос-картинка бесполезен для базы знаний.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.list-number-custom {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: li;  
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-gap: 2em;
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 2em;
}

.list-number-custom > li {
  padding: 15px 0 15px 40px;
  position: relative;  
}

.list-number-custom > li:before {
  counter-increment: li;
  content: counter(li) " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: -15px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background: tomato;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<ol class="list-number-custom">
  <li>list</li>
  <li>list</li>
  <li>list</li>
  <li>list</li>
  <li>list</li>
  <li>list</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Если текст у элемента в несколько строк, то иконки на разной высоте

Comment: @rammtw https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/6t8z838q/

Answer (score 1):

```
<ol>
    <li class="col-xs-4">text 1
    <li class="col-xs-4">text 2
    <li class="col-xs-4">text 3
    <li class="col-xs-4">text 4
    <li class="col-xs-4">text 5
</ol>
```